# chat on assembly using serial port

Tags: assembly, x86, serial-port, dos, interruption

I'm working on a chat using assembly and i got this huge doubt, I'm currently using

int 21,
AH= 0Ah

to get a string from  the keyboard wich I will later send, char by char, through the serial port, but then i was wondering how, will I receive a msg from the other computer running the same program if this one is in a interruption waiting for me to input a string.

How can i get around the fact that when inputing a string, the whole program is interrupted and anything being sent on the mean time will be lost?

Comment: Well, it's usual to run a separate read thread.  The thought of calling CreateThread() from assembler is rather daunting :(

Comment: @Martin: there's no CreateThread under DOS. Note the OP mentioning int21h. Also, read the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [function 6 with `DL` = 0FFh](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2559.htm).

It will return immediately either with data or without. It won't wait for keyboard input.